# Excluding headers from code generated through Postman for a defined request?

Tags: curl, postman, postman-pre-request-script

When developing, it's oftentimes very helpful to be able to copy the requests that you are making as cURLs when presenting bugs or troubleshooting with other team members. However, when you use the Generate Code Snippets feature, it will automatically copy all of the headers that you used in the request, including the Authorization header, which you obviously don't want to share with team members.

Is there a way to change the settings for the code generation or otherwise programmatically dictate to Postman not to add certain headers to the request being generated as code?

Answer (score 1):

You have to un-tick the headers on the headers tab and then generate the code.